# Don't Alert when Gated Checkin Fails

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-alerts

We have a team alert in TFS 2015 that sends an email out to all developers whenever one of our builds fails.

I'd like to modify it to not issue emails when someone fails a private build, or a private gated check-in fails (we don't use gated check-ins by default). In these cases, a separate alert will issue to just the individual developer.

Below is the current criteria

[image: Alert Criteria]

However, when I tried to run a manual gated check-in just now, the build failure issued an email to the entire team.

What additional conditions are required to ensure that these emails are not generated when I create a build using a shelveset - whether or not I choose to automatically commit the changes on success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no private gated check-in build, "gated check-in build" **is not Private build.**

> You queue a private build if you want to build the changes that you
>   have put into a shelveset.

More detail info with private build in TFS, please refer this MSDN link:
[Queue a build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181722(v=vs.120).aspx)

When you are going to use the private build and not issue emails when someone fails, you can add a **build reason** not contain *check in shelvest* as a workaroud.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it would do what I'm after.

Answer (score -1):

The part above your screen shot is the part that identifies if the alert is being configured for a Team (sends to everyone) or a personal alert (just to you).